# Hosted build on VSO with Azure SDK 2.8 fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-sdk-.net

We recently updated our Azure SDK to 2.8.
Now when building our solution on VSO hosted build we get build errors.

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\
>   2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found.
>   Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I've found another one with similar issues with a question posted on MSDN but without any answers. [Support for Azure SDK 2.8 in hosted build](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/15bc53da-36d0-4fe0-b882-d5522856fa95/support-for-azure-sdk-28-in-hosted-build?forum=TFService)

Anyone know how to get around this issue? Do we have to downgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are working on the update now. Azure 2.8 should be on the build machines week of Nov. 30.

Update: We ran into a couple of issues and still hope to have this completed this week, but it may slip into next week.

Update Dec. 17: We finally got the updated image with Azure 2.8 into production yesterday. Sorry for the long delay.

Comment: 2h 36min left of Monday "next week", how much longer will the "slipping" last?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say I can only apologize. The team's had a tough time working through some issues with this one.

Comment: Is it coming soon? I mean is it worth waiting for a few days or just go ahead and deploy our own build agent?

Comment: I've asked for an update on the status this morning. I would say wait, but I'm clearly an optimist. I'll add more when I get more info today.

Comment: It's going to be longer - hopefully some time next week - because the team hit more issues with trying to get the base image updated. I'm sorry about the delay.

Comment: Good news...it's finally out. Sorry it took so terribly long.

Comment: Is there going to be a public statement along the lines of: "This took X days to complete because we were contending with XYZ issues. These have been resolved and future upgrades will be smoother as a result." I know I'm curious to know what happened. :)

Comment: My build is still failing with this error message, as of a few minutes ago. Perhaps the fix hasn't been rolled out everywhere?

Comment: It is supposed to be on all build machines. What is your account URL?

Comment: We also just upgraded all of our solutions to Azure SDK 2.8.1 and our builds are failing on VSO hosted builds. "The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."

Comment: @BuckHodges, I am experiencing the same problem as Bill. Still cannot publish via build controller targeting Azude SDK 2.8.1. Can we get an update on this please?

Comment: @JohnWasham I have submitted a Microsoft support ticket. I'll let you know when we find something out soon.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've found out we've updated one type of builds and not the other (counter to my "all build machines" statement above). The build machines that use the new build system have Azure 2.8. The images for the build machine used by the older XAML-based builds do not have it. Yes, I realize how bad this sounds as I am writing it, and I apologize. I'll let you know when I have a date for this to be fixed.

Comment: @BuckHodges, understood, thanks for the update. It's better at least knowing that a fix is coming.

Comment: @JohnWasham Microsoft closed the ticket on me as they confirmed it was an issue with no time given for a fix. However, I was able to build with no problems 1/26/2016.  Give it a try.

Comment: @BuckHodges any update on this issue, my automated builds are still bombing :(

Answer (score 2):

The latest Azure SDK supported on Hosted build is 2.7. Refer to [Hosted build controller](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs) for details.

To build your solution, you'd either downgrade Azure SDK version to 2.7 or [deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows) and install Azure SDK 2.8 on it.

Comment: According to this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/services/hosted-build-controller Azure SDK 2.8 is supposed to be installed on the hosted build controllers. It appears to not be as of 12/23.